# reading n bytes from a binary file until end of file in verilog

Tags: file, io, verilog

I have a binary file. I need to read 512 bits every time from it until the file ends and pass it as input to my design. I am using readmemh/readmemb to read from the file.  but we have to specify the size of memory array before readmemh to pass as its argument. so if we don't know the depth of the register how can we read the complete binary file.

```
reg [511:0]packet[1:0]; 
$readmemh("abc.bin",packet); //this abc.bin has 237kb size
```

what should be the depth of memory 'packet'?

Comment: Can you clarify: Do you have a true binary file, or an ASCII file with 1 and 0 characters? Do you know of a maximum possible depth?

Comment: My file contains hex values. I converted an image to hex using matlab and gave that file as input here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options

- If there is a maximum possible size for the file, just declare the array with the maximum size needed. The remaining elements will be left uninitialized (`X`) by `$readmemh`.
- Pass a parameter or macro definition on the command line with the array size when you compile your design. The commands will depend on the tool you're using.
- Instead of reading the entire file into an array, read it one line at a time using `$fscanf(fd,"%h", value)`. The `value` can be applied to your inputs as needed.

---

```
do begin
  repeat (64) begin
    code = $fscanf(fd,"%h", value); // get byte
    pattern = {pattern,value};      // shift into pattern
  end
  send_to_dut(pattern);
end while (code == 1);
```

Comment: hi dave_59, my  hex file contains 8 bits in each line. I need to read first 512 bits to one reg and give it as input to my design. then the next 512 bits and so on..  if I read using readmemh or fscanf, and the register is 512 bit register its giving all zeros on MSBs other than last 8 bits. how can I change this

Comment: It would help to have all this information from the beginning. See updated example

Answer (score 0):

The $readmemh method is not ideal for this type of continuous data processing.

Instead I would use the same method you would in standard programming language: 
Open a file, read the data you need from it, close the file. This way you can process files of many megabytes size, but you do not need many megabyte of storage.

```
fd = $fopen(filename,"rb");
if (fd==0)
begin
   $display("%m @%0t: Could not open file '%s'",$time,filename);
   $stop;     
end
else
begin
   $display("%m @%0t: Opened %s for reading",$time,filename);
   file_is_open = 1'b1;
end

if (file_is_open)
  value= $fgetc(fd);
```

WARNING:
This uses a binary file. Your $readmemh uses an ASCII file. You can, if you want,  read an ASCII file but then you have to do the ASCII to hex conversion yourself writing a small Verilog function.